# Array of pointers with non-sequential addresses

Tags: c, pointers

I am working on some firmware for an ARM mcu using S32 Design Studio, which is an Eclipse-based IDE.

I was debugging some incorrect behavior I encountered with a global variable (yes I know that global is not preferred when local will do).

The global variable is an array of uint16_t pointers.   When I read out the values of the last two elements using this array, I get an unexpected result.

In the IDE, I can pause the program right at the start of main().  When I hover over the variable it shows me the addresses and contents of the array elements.

[image: first array with weird addresses]

A second array that is similar works fine:
[image: second array with sequential addresses]

Not sure how to debug this further.  I'm also scratching my head about why the address of the whole array seems to point to the "end" of the array rather than to the first element.  Any why that would happen in the middle of the misbehaving array.

I confirmed that compiler optimizations are set to None.

```
uint16_t vshut  = 2000;
uint16_t vrec   = 2400;
uint16_t durams = 3000;
uint16_t otshut = 1100;
uint16_t scen   = 0;
uint16_t ldcos  = 0;
uint16_t * safetysettings[6] = {&vshut, &vrec, &durams, &otshut, &scen, &ldcos};

uint16_t tax1 = 2000;
uint16_t tax2 = 2400;
uint16_t tax3 = 3000;
uint16_t tax4 = 1100;
uint16_t tax5 = 0x0007;
uint16_t tax6 = 0x0009;
uint16_t * ssettings[6] = {&tax1, &tax2, &tax3, &tax4, &tax5, &tax6};
```

Edit:

Elsewhere in the code these values are manipulated, then read out using a separate function:

```
update_databus_safetysettings(safetysettings);
```

```
void update_databus_safetysettings(uint16_t * settings[]){
    holt_6135_write_SA_data_array(RT1_CtrlWord_TxSA12 + 1, settings[0], 6, 0);
}
```

```
void holt_6135_write_SA_data_array(uint16_t desc1word, uint16_t * data, uint8_t count, uint8_t offset){
    enaMAP(1);
    Write_6131LowReg(MAP_1,desc1word);  // address=0x04C9; contents=0x0628;
    uint16_t addr = Read_6131_1word();

    for(uint8_t i = 0; i<count; i++){
        Write_6131LowReg(MAP_1,addr+2+offset+i);  // first word is msg info, second is time tag, and third is the first data word.
        Write_6131_1word(*(data+i));
    }
}
```

If I have those globals initialized to zero, incorrect data is written with Write_6131_1word.

If I have them initialized to non-zero, it appears to work correctly.

Edit 2:

The only other place that touches these values is a function that reads them in:

```
read_databus_safetysettings(safetysettings);
```

```
void read_databus_safetysettings(uint16_t * settings[]){
    holt_6135_readmem_nwords(RT1_CtrlWord_RxSA11+1, settings, 5); // note that during Rx11 only first 5 datawords are used, even though the pointer array has 6 elements.
}
```

```
void holt_6135_readmem_nwords(uint16_t addr, uint16_t * datawords[], uint8_t count){
    uint16_t data;
    enaMAP(3);
    Write_6131LowReg(MAP_3,addr);
    data = Read_6131_1word();
    //  Write_6131LowReg(MAP_3,data);
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < count; i++){
        Write_6131LowReg(MAP_3,data+2+i);
        *(datawords[i]) = Read_6131_1word();
    }
}
```

High-level what is happening here is that I am writing some data to/from a serial communications IC over an SPI bus.  That is what some of the low-level functions are doing.

Edit 3:

Based on the feedback I received I came up with a simple program that I think correctly demonstrates the way it is supposed to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


void read_vals(uint16_t ** settings){
    for(int ind = 0; ind < 6; ind++){
        *settings[ind] =  2*ind;
    }
}

void print_vals(uint16_t ** settings){
    for(int ind = 0; ind < 6; ind++){
        printf("settings[%d]: %d\n",ind, *settings[ind]);
    }
}

uint16_t vshut  = 2000;         
uint16_t vrec   = 2400;
uint16_t durams = 3000;
uint16_t otshut = 1100;                 
uint16_t scen   = 0;    
uint16_t ldcos  = 0;    
uint16_t * safetysettings[6] = {&vshut, &vrec, &durams, &otshut, &scen, &ldcos};
uint16_t ** ssptr = &safetysettings[0];

int main()
{

    // print_vals(&safetysettings[0]);
    // read_vals(&safetysettings[0]);
    // print_vals(&safetysettings[0]);

    print_vals(ssptr);
    read_vals(ssptr);
    print_vals(ssptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problems here. The debugger is showing exactly what I would expect, given that code.

Comment: I don' undertand the question really. Why are the addresses surprising?

Comment: Hint: Do you notice anything else different about those two variables? To what value are they initialized?

Comment: Global variables that are initialized to 0 are put in a different memory area than other variables, because zero-initialization can be optimized.

Comment: Re “I get an unexpected result”: **Never** describe a problem so vaguely. State **exactly** what text you observe and **exactly** what text you expect instead. State what you think the differences are.

Comment: Indeed - if I change those from zero the addresses are continuous.    Could it be that my code is screwing up elsewhere because if I do something like *(ptr + 1) it won't find a non-sequential location?

Comment: The pointers can point anywhere. Why do you think they need to point to sequential addresses? Why won't you just explain what the *actual* problem is that you're encountering?

Comment: So your complaint is not that “an array of pointers” has non-sequential addresses. Your complaint (or surprise) is that `scen` and `ldcos` have addresses that differ considerably from other objects (such as `otshut`, `durams`) even though they have similar definitions. That is what you should have written.

Comment: "I was debugging some **incorrect behavior** ..." okay but why don't you describe what that **incorrect behavior** is? What you have posted is perfectly fine behavior

Comment: My problem was that the last two elements weren't be read out correctly elsewhere in the program.  My observation was that these had non-sequential addresses.  If I initialize the globals to non-zero, the addresses become sequential, and the misbehavior of the read goes away.

Comment: @mzap So that's the problem you should have asked about... the incorrect reads... Instead you jumped to some wrong conclusion and asked about something completely different which by the way is perfectly fine.

Comment: So instead of getting your real problem solved you can get an answer telling you why variables in memory isn't always placed in consecutive memory. But your real problem/question remains unsolved.

Comment: Appreciate everyone's comments here.  Sorry if I framed the question incorrectly.  

I am still curious about the address of the array pointing to the end of the array and not the first element.  Or is it that the array has its own address which happens to be  placed after the elements because it was declared after them?

Comment: @mzap In above comment you write " I am still curious about the address of the array pointing to the end of the array...." That's **not** what's going on here. It's the array that is located in memory just after `otshut`.

Comment: @mzap And if you look at the other array you'll see the same. It's just located just after `tax6`.

Comment: @mzap Oh... And don't concentrate about that. It doesn't matter. Individual variables may be located anywhere in memory. It doesn't matter. If you program has incorrect behavior the root cause is something different.

Comment: Re “I am still curious about the address of the array pointing to the end of the array and not the first element”: The address of `safetysettings` is shown as `0x1ffe0f84`. That is indeed where the array is. That is its start. The next address shown, `0x1ffe0f7c`, is not the address of the array or anything in it. It is the value of element 0 of the array, which is a pointer to `vshut`. `vshut` is at `0x1ffe0f7c`, so that is the value that appears in the array. Its location is different from the array’s.

Comment: "I'm also scratching my head about why the address of the whole array seems to point to the "end" of the array rather than to the first element." You seem to think the array 'overlays' or 'embeds' the variables. That is not the case.

Comment: If your program's correct behavior relies on separate variables being in successive memory locations, then your code suffers from UB. I'm guessing your code gets a pointer from the array, then increments that pointer, where it _should_ have gotten back to the array and from there proceed to the next element.

Comment: I am really sorry.  Let me add another edit to try to complete the picture.

Comment: @mzap For layout of variables in memory at a look at this https://ideone.com/ytt82h Notice how the compiler reorders the memory location compared to the order of variables in the C code

Comment: @EricPostpischil The UB I mentioned is in function `holt_6135_write_SA_data_array`, parameter `data`. That's not a pointer to an array element, that's a pointer to one of the separate variables (`vshut`). Taking `*(data+i)` is very very wrong.

Comment: @RuudHelderman: I already wrote that up in my answer, five minutes before your comment.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Apologies, I was distracted by earlier claims about buffer overrun. Glad to see we agree to agree.

Comment: Why is the word "safety" all over this bleak code? This better not be safety-related software.

Comment: Anyway, this might be of interest: [What resides in the different memory types of a microcontroller?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237740/what-resides-in-the-different-memory-types-of-a-microcontroller/237759#237759)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scen` and `ldcos` are zero-initialized and are put in a program section that the program loader and/or operating system initialize to zeros.

The other objects are initialized with non-zero data and are put in a program section that is initialized by reading the data from the program’s executable file on disk.

So they are in different areas in memory.

> If I have those globals initialized to zero, incorrect data is written with Write_6131_1word.
>
> If I have them initialized to non-zero, it appears to work correctly.

This is consistent with the incorrect implementation of `holt_6135_write_SA_data_array` now shown in your question paired with the correct (or at least not incorrect in the same way) implementation of `holt_6135_readmem_nwords`. The read routine correctly looks up the addresses of the words in the `settings` array and writes the values to the correct objects. The write routine incorrectly uses consecutive addresses for the words, as explained below. When `scen` and `ldcos` are zero-initialized, they are in a different program section, so the incorrect code in the write routine fails to fetch them. When they are non-zero-initialized, they are consecutive with the other words, so the incorrect code in the write routine does fetch them.

This code is wrong:

```
update_databus_safetysettings(safetysettings);
…
void update_databus_safetysettings(uint16_t * settings[]){
    holt_6135_write_SA_data_array(RT1_CtrlWord_TxSA12 + 1, settings[0], 6, 0);
}
…
void holt_6135_write_SA_data_array(uint16_t desc1word, uint16_t * data, uint8_t count, uint8_t offset){
    enaMAP(1);
    Write_6131LowReg(MAP_1,desc1word);  // address=0x04C9; contents=0x0628;
    uint16_t addr = Read_6131_1word();

    for(uint8_t i = 0; i<count; i++){
        Write_6131LowReg(MAP_1,addr+2+offset+i);  // first word is msg info, second is time tag, and third is the first data word.
        Write_6131_1word(*(data+i));
    }
}
```

`safetysettings` is an array of six pointers. You pass `settings[0]` to `holt_6135_write_SA_data_array`. `settings[0]` is the address of `vshut`. That is a single `uint16_t` object. It is passed for the `data` parameter of `holt_6135_write_SA_data_array`, and you pass `6` for `count`.

In `holt_6135_write_SA_data_array`, you index `data` with `*(data+i)`, for `i` from zero (inclusive) to `count` (exclusive). That is wrong, because only `data+0` is a valid address of an object for that pointer. Using `data+1`, `data+2`, and so on to access objects are not valid uses of that pointer.

If you want the routine to write the six `uint16_t` objects listed in settings, you need to pass it the address of the first element in the array, `settings`, not the value of the first element. The parameter would have type `uint16_t **` instead of `uint16_t *`, and you would look up each element of the array and then fetch the `uint16_t` it points to, with `*data[i]` instead of `*(data+i)`.

Comment: basic question about stack overflow - I wish to make a comment with some code snippet, but comments don't seem to be a place for that.  I could edit the original post, but that could be confusing.  Do I maybe click Answer Your Question and put further code and questions in that?

Comment: @mzap: Questions should be edited to clarify them. Adding code to clarify a question is fine. Adding code to add a new question is not. Stack Overflow is not an interactive debugging service. A primary purpose is to serve as a durable repository of questions and answers for future users. Questions should be static. They should also be specific, and they should be well-described so they are easy to search. Answering debugging questions arose only out of incidental questions and repeated use, but it is not a main purpose of Stack Overflow. To ask a new question, write a new post.

Comment: Eric many thanks for your thoughtful responses.   Your suggestion makes sense, but I'm having a bit of difficulty getting it to work.  I will follow up with a new, separate question.